# android app crashes without error and too many pictures are downloading?

Tags: android, heap-memory

my application downloads many pictures. 2 pictures per model. And there are around 20 models. Some of these pictures are very large svg's and some of them are png's.

I get the image url through another file, then i check if the url ends with svg or png , if the url ends with ".png" i use picasso and if it ends with ".svg" i use glide.

I am using the Recyclerview. I display the models in a  list.

here is the adapters **onBindViewHolder** method (where i download and set the images in the imageview through picasso or glide):

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
    final Object object= objectList.get(i);

    requestBuilder = Glide.with(customViewHolder.imageViewHomeTeam.getContext())
            .using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, customViewHolder.imageViewHomeTeam.getContext()), InputStream.class)
            .from(Uri.class)
            .as(SVG.class)
            .transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
            .sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
            .cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<SVG>(new SvgDecoder()))
            .decoder(new SvgDecoder())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholdererror)
            .animate(android.R.anim.fade_in)
            .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());

        if (object.getImageUrl().isEmpty() || object.getImageUrl().equals("null"))
        {
            customViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
        }
        else
        {

            if (object.getImageUrl().endsWith(".svg"))
            {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(object.getImageUrl());
                requestBuilder
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                        .load(uri)
                        .into(customViewHolder.imageView);
            }
            else {
                Picasso.with(customViewHolder.imageView.getContext())
                        .load(object.getImageUrl())
                        .resize(300, 300) // because some images are very big
                        .onlyScaleDown()
                        .skipMemoryCache()
                        .error(R.drawable.placeholdererror)
                        .into(customViewHolder.imageView);
            }

        }
    customViewHolder.textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(object.getTitle))); // .fromHtml because i am getting the string from another file through json like the images // (AsyncTask)

}
```

**Now my Problem:** i think the application lowkey is overwhelmed with the amount of images and there size, because the app just crashes without any errors and i think i found something in the logcat what has something to do with this:

```
11-25 03:42:04.114 1204-1204/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to     13.726MB for 3072012-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:04.470 1204-1204/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 19.971MB for 6553612-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:05.066 14886-14886/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 16.590MB for 8294412-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:06.166 14886-14886/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 48.230MB for 33177612-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:14.166 14886-14886/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 45.887MB for 1205580-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:15.314 14886-14924/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 48.114MB for 2295784-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:15.618 14886-14924/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 50.036MB for 2295784-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:15.770 14886-14924/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 52.223MB for 2295784-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:15.826 14886-14924/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 50.034MB for 2295784-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:15.918 14886-14924/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 48.945MB for 1147875-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:16.002 14886-14924/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 49.751MB for 860909-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:16.106 14886-14924/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 50.562MB for 849728-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:16.518 14886-14924/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 63.914MB for 16009616-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:18.914 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          bf9f25a4  b7eed17c  [heap]
11-25 03:42:18.914 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     a6a0b000-a94b3000 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
11-25 03:42:18.914 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     a94b3000-aa8e5000 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
11-25 03:42:18.914 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     aa8e5000-b6169000 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
11-25 03:42:19.354 1204-1204/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 13.722MB for 3072012-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:19.506 1413-1413/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 34.462MB for 91212-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:19.542 1204-1204/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 19.972MB for 6553612-byte allocation
11-25 03:42:20.374 619-1479/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 14886 uid 10037
```

The first objects are getting their images but then everything is getting too much and the app crashes without any errormessage.

It is because of the images, because i tested the app without the images and it worked fine.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: what device you are using for testing? I think the error is because the image is using too much memory in your device.. every android device has its own size limit. so either you process the image or put android:largeHeap="true" in manifest.. but you should use largeHeap settings as last resort

Comment: both emulator and device and yes you are right the images are may taking too much memory. what could i do beside setting android:largeHeap="true" in manifest?

Comment: As you have mentioned that you are handling large file size in download don't load it directly to Adapter, setting android:largeHeap=true is not going to help you as well. So as you know the list of images , USe download Manager to download all the files to specific folder inside app folder. Load it to adapter by scaling it down, think your huge svg is causing issues

Comment: thank you very much for that advice. i will try it. do you know any examples?

Comment: @HourGlass but DownloadManager doesnt support svg images.

Comment: @AhmedTA you could try reducing the image size when you sending it on server code or everytime you receive on your app code..